# Move values to back of an np.array()

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to create the most efficient (not nicest/prettiest) way of moving particular values within an np.array() to the back of said array.

I currently have two different solutions:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython = True)
def move_to_back_a(a, value):
    new_a = []

    total_values = 0

    for v in a:
        if v == value:
            total_values += 1
        else:
            new_a.append(v)

    return new_a + [value] * total_values

@jit(nopython = True)
def move_to_back_b(a, value):
    total_values = np.count_nonzero(a == value)

    ind = a == value
    a = a[~ind]

    return np.append(a, [value] * total_values)
```

Which give the following output:

```
In [7]: move_to_back_a(np.array([2,3,24,24,24,1]), 24)
Out[7]: [2, 3, 1, 24, 24, 24]

In [8]: move_to_back_b(np.array([2,3,24,24,24,1]), 24)
Out[8]: array([ 2,  3,  1, 24, 24, 24], dtype=int64)
```

It doesn't really matter whether I get back my output as a list or as an array, though I expect that returning an array will be more helpful in my future code.

The current timing on these tests is as follows:

```
In [9]: %timeit move_to_back_a(np.array([2,3,24,24,24,1]), 24)
2.28 µs ± 20.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit move_to_back_b(np.array([2,3,24,24,24,1]), 24)
3.1 µs ± 50.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Is there any way to make this code even faster?

Comment: Which Python/NumPy/numba version are you using? When I run it using 3.69/1.13.3/0.45.1 I get a numba error about `np.count_nonzero` being used in a wrong way

Comment: @Graipher I'm using 3.7/1.16.4/0.46.0 for Python, NumPy and Numba, respectively.

Comment: Is this the typical size of your arrays or can they get larger?

Comment: @MennoVanDijk: OK, I just updated to Numba 0.47.0, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second function is faster for me when simplifying it like this:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def move_to_back_c(a, value):
    mask = a == value
    return np.append(a[~mask], a[mask])
```

In addition, Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), recommends *not* surrounding a `=` with spaces if it is used for keyword arguments, like your `nopython=True`.

Since `numba` apparently [recently gained generator support](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.18.1/developer/generators.html), this might also be worth checking out:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def _move_to_back_d(a, value):
    count = 0
    for x in a:
        if x != value:
            yield x
        else:
            count += 1
    for _ in range(count):
        yield value

@jit(nopython=True)
def move_to_back_d(a, value):
    return list(_move_to_back_d(a, value))
```

The timings I get on my machine for the given testcase are:

```
move_to_back_a    1.63 µs ± 14.5 ns
move_to_back_b    2.33 µs ± 21 ns
move_to_back_c    1.92 µs ± 17.5 ns
move_to_back_d    1.66 µs ± 9.69 ns
```

What is in the end as least as important is the scaling behavior, though. Here are some timings using larger arrays:

```
np.random.seed(42)
x = [(np.random.randint(0, 100, n), 42) for n in np.logspace(1, 7, dtype=int)]
```

[image]

While slightly slower for small arrays, for larger the mask approach is consistently faster.

Comment: Thanks for the solution as well as the recommendation on style. I do get ~ `6.5 µs` on this solution, which is quite a bit slower than `move_to_back_a()`.

Comment: @MennoVanDijk: Did you compare it either with both `@jit` or both without, so it is fair?

Comment: Just did, unfortunately, this still consistently runs about `0.3 µs` above `move_to_back_a()`

Comment: @MennoVanDijk: Added timings and another function.

Comment: Was waiting with accepting this answer in hopes of receiving other answers. I have just accepted it since there does not seem to be more coming my way. Thanks a bunch for helping me with this.

Comment: @MennoVanDijk: Yes, some more alternatives and maybe reviews of the other stuff would ahve been nice. Glad to have helped some, though!